# Some postcode searches returning inaccurate results

Tags: here-api

I'm using the Here Geocoder API using free-form input and getting random results when searching for postcodes in the Isle of Man.

I haven't tried all postcodes but the couple I have tested (from customer complaints) do appear to have a problem.

You can test the postcodes on the examples page and see the response yourself - https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoder

When searching for the postcode `IM4 4LH` the response returns an address for `IP4 4LH` but if you search for `IM4 4` you get the right general area.

Another example is if you search for `IM5 1HD` you get the right response but if you search for `IM51HD` you instead get a response with `IP5 1HD` as the postcode.

`IM4 4LH` & `IM5 1HD` are legitimate postcode areas so I was wondering if there is something else we can do to more accurately target postcodes.

I know results could be more accurate with more search data but I would have thought a postcode on it's own would be more than enough.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the core map for United Kingdom and for Isle of Man only sector postal codes are available. E.g. " IM5 1".

The Geocoder additionally uses an extra product which provides the full postal codes (seven digits). Until last quarter they were covering only United Kingdom. E.g. postal code " IP5 1HD" is coming from these products.

Starting from this quarter it will cover also Isle of Man. This still need to be integrated  into the Geocoder database. As soon as we are done, full postal codes will also be available for Isle of Man.

We work on it but cannot yet commit on a timeline.