# Does HERE Geocoding not support UK postcode units?

Tags: here-api

I try to geocode UK postcodes with the HERE geocoding [REST API](https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/).

While searches for the UK postcode sector work (e.g.: `geocode?q=ME3 9&in=countryCode:GBR` ), there seem to be no results for postcode units ( `geocode?q=ME3 9EJ&in=countryCode:GBR` ).

These are just giving back the postcode sector.

I also tried using the `qq` parameter ( `geocode?qq=postalCode=ME3 9E`) but with the same result.

This question seems to be similar to [Some postcode searches returning inaccurate results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536361/some-postcode-searches-returning-inaccurate-results) but since this uses an old API endpoint and on https://wego.here.com the postcode unit search seems to be accurate I will ask again.

Do I structure my queries in a wrong way, is there a parameter that I am overlooking or are postcode units unsupported?

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id={{app_id}}&app_code={{app_code}}&postalCode=ME3 9EJ&country=GBR

Comment: While this works, unfortunately it uses the old API (v6.2 and not v7)

Comment: The API will not disappear before quite some time so keep on using it as it works well!